# Symfony2 1553 mysql error fixind

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am getting an 1553 error everytime I want to update my database from the console. This is the error:

General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'idPartner': needed in a foreign key constraint.

So as I read other SO questions i found that I need to drop the Foreign key and create it again? So i dropped it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE bet DROP FOREIGN KEY idPartner ;
```

After this I lose all the foreign tables data (and I need it). However I dont get the error then.

So after dropping I want to create the Foreign key relationship again so I do:

```
ALTER TABLE `bet` ADD CONSTRAINT `idPartner` FOREIGN KEY (`idPartner`) REFERENCES `lottery`.`partner`(`idPartner`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Aaaand I get the same error again... What can I do?

The Query:

```
$php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
Updating database schema...

[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]
An exception occured while executing 'DROP INDEX idPartner ON bet':
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'idPartner': needed in a foreign key constraint

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1553 Cannot drop index 'idPartner': needed in a foreign key constraint
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

These need to be for what you need, you can read more from here:

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html
>
> When an UPDATE or DELETE operation affects a key value in the parent
>   table that has matching rows in the child table, the result depends on
>   the referential action specified using ON UPDATE and ON DELETE
>   subclauses of the FOREIGN KEY clause. MySQL supports five options
>   regarding the action to be taken, listed here:
>
> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and
>   automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>   Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between
>   two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act
>   on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes I have made the changes, accordingly to the documentation and my needs but I still get the error. I dont think this is the problem...

Comment: can you edit your post and show the query you are using, the one that gives  you errors

Comment: I understood you wrong, what you want to do, I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: Actually this is not my project. This was already made when I got it and because of this error I cant continue to update the project. What do you mean by saying it is not possible? What is not possible?